How to get the value of "SharedPreferences" in another file in Flutter?
I am working on a project where I wanted to submit a Form. Now, I want to submit that Form only once and then show the next screen. If the user signs in again and has already submitted the form that form screen will not show but another screen will show. For this purpose, I am using SharedPreferences. What I am doing is saving a bool value in SharedPreferences in the form screen and then accessing that value in "main.dart" file. However, I am not getting a stored value. I do not know why. Any help? Here is my code snippet. Note, that I am using an iOS simulator.
In the form screen, I am doing this.
  SharedPreferences? _prefs;
   @override
  void initState() {
    //_selectedCrops = _crops;
    super.initState();

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _prefs = value;
      });
    });
  }

Then in the submit button, I set its value to true.
_prefs!.setBool('form_submitted', true);

Now, in the "main.dart" file.
  SharedPreferences? _prefs;
  bool formSubmitted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _prefs = value;
        formSubmitted = _prefs!.getBool('form_submitted') ?? false;
      });
    });

    log('form submitted: $formSubmitted');
    //Here I am always getting false.

    super.initState();
  }


while using .then doest hold the next statemented. you can put the log inside  then's body.  A better solution can be using FutureBuilder depends on your ux

@Md.YeasinSheikh, now I am getting true. However. I wanted to use the "formSubmitted" value in the build to access another screen. How can then I access that value? I cannot use FutureBuilder because I wanted to use a static bool value as a condition.

It will take some frame(<few milis) to get the the data from SharedPreferences and you cant directly get the value on first frame. but,  if you have already fetch the bool on main file, you can pass the  formSubmitted  to the form page.

formSubmitted ? const FormScreen() : OtherScreen());. The issue is that I only get value in .then scope. Outside the scope, the value remained false. How can I use that value outside the scope?

You can use  FutureBuild and then once data is loaded, render the corresponding screen.

Okay, I will try.

Stop fetching the instance of sharedprefs repeatedly.  See my video on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yM2t-M6iAI

Using FutureBuilder, I achieved the desired result.
In the form screen, I set the value in the submit button using _setValue() function.
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  late Future<bool> _formSubmitted;

  Future<void> _setValue(bool value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

    setState(() async {
      await prefs.setBool('form_submitted', value).then((bool success) {});
    });
  }

Then in the main.dart file
 final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 late Future<bool> formSubmitted;

 @override
  void initState() {
    formSubmitted = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return prefs.getBool('form_submitted') ?? false;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

Then use FutureBuilder to select the desired screen
....
child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: formSubmitted,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data == true) {
                        return OtherScreen();
                      } else {
                        return const FormScreen();
                      }
                    }),


         @override
          void initState() {
    //Part 1
            SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
              setState(() {
                _prefs = value;
                formSubmitted = _prefs!.getBool('form_submitted') ?? false;
              });
            });
   //
Part 2
            log('form submitted: $formSubmitted');
            //Here I am always getting false.
        
            super.initState();
          }

Here the part 1 and part 2 are running Asynchronously. Therefore, it is possible that the log command is called before the data is fetched from SharedPreferences. As a workaround, you can use the "await" to make sure the boolean value is fetched before calling the log command like this:
_prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
formSubmitted = _prefs!.getBool('form_submitted') ?? false;

